# What am I doing wrong with this Wheatstone Bridge?

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis

Experienced experimentalists, be aware that this is probably going to sound like a stupid question:
I am having a LOT of trouble predicting the output of this Wheatstone bridge circuit.

[image]
I am trying to predict the third harmonic voltage read by the lock-in amplifier (I am preparing something resembling a 3-omega setup and need to get this figured out first).

I know how to predict the voltage between 1 and 2 (the first harmonic voltage), from what I understand it is

$$\Delta V = V_{source}\left(\frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2} - \frac{R_4}{R_3+R_4}\right).$$

However, here are two plots showing the predictions made for the bridge output when I just change $R_4$ keeping $R_1=R_2=R_3=1K\Omega$. I've compared these to the actual measurements I get with the lock-in (corrected for the fact that it reads rms voltage).
[image]
[image]
Notice that the predictions are in volts, while I am measuring millivolts!
The relationship between my predictions and the measured values is either linear or quadratic.
[image]

Basically, I'm just thoroughly confused about what is happening.

Here are the actual data arrays for reference:

Resistance(Ohms) = $[.32,10,10^2,10^3,10^4,10^5,10^6,10^7,2*10^3,6*10^3,600]$

Prediction(Volts) = [-.499,-.489,-.406,.00605,.412,.491,.5,.501,.172,.361,-.119]

Measured (mV) = 
[3.277,3.285,3.454,4.463,6.218,6.732,6.800,6.812,5.053,5.936,4.096]

Picture of the Setup:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: @Qmechanic possibly! I will move it there if you think that is best.

Comment: Actually, I don't think this is an EE question. If it was, there would be no harmonics because the system is completely linear. The harmonics arise because of **thermal** conductivity and its time constants...that's physics to me.

Comment: There are no harmonics if everything is linear. If the resistors change value with self-heating then you can get harmonics.

Comment: 3-omega temperature measurements are not commonly found. This article https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/16dd/6695731df18340b0755c35e9879f00ed5f9f.pdf is a good starting place. In effect, the change in resistance due to temperature effects means that the circuit is not linear if (for instance) R2 is not a fixed (zero TC) resistance.

Comment: Elliot, that would explain the lack of good third harmonic measurments, thanks!
(Although I do seem to be able to get something at n=2)
Regardless, I am still confused about how to reconcile the 1 omega outputs with what I think they should be, which seems like it might be an EE question.

Comment: @WyattKuehster Normally you have to gain up the voltage from the wheatstone bridge, what does the actual circuit look like?

Comment: The x-axis of your top graph makes no sense.  If the resistors are 1K what is meaning of R4= 7.5?  How do you get a negative R4 for your first data point?Anyway, it looks to me like you are measuring the third harmonic distortion of your signal generator. What is the THD specification of that instrument? What are the theoretical requirements for this specification to make good measurements?

Comment: @user69795 Excuse me! The plot has been fixed. What I mean is $R_4$ varies but the other three are fixed at about 1K Ohm.

Comment: @laptop2d the actual circuit is put together on a breadboard, I put a picture at the bottom of the question.

Comment: Have you simulated what happens if the fixed resistors are not exactly 1k? Especially if R1/R2 is not 1?

Comment: To see the operation of a conventional Wheatstone bridge, set your lock in amplifier to look at the fundamental of the signal generator frequency.  In the 3-omega  theory, there is no third harmonic unless you have a single resistor with a large change in resistance with temperature, and the other three resistors have a low T.C.  You have a setup with four conventional carbon film resistors, all with the same, (and a moderate) T. C.  To use the 3-omega method, you have to be more careful than you are. Read the papers more carefully.  You are now measuring the distortion of your signal source.

Comment: What frequency are you using for your function generator?

Comment: @user69795 I am not trying to make a 3 Omega measurement yet, I'm just trying to understand what's happening with this circuit.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast Somewhat, yes. The predicted voltages are the outputs using the measured resistances on an ohmmeter.  I can get my predicted curve to almost fit by playing with the resistances a little bit, but I also have to add a strange factor of 1/2 and change the - to a +. Even then, the curve isn't even close to fitting within the sensitivity of the lock-in, which is why I am concerned that there is something wrong with my formula.
(Sidenote: I wish I could add pictures to comments, my question is getting crowded. Is it frowned upon to make a new question with the advances I have made?)